# Import module after Py_Initialize

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

Today, I use `PyImport_AppendInittab` to append python modules built in C. `PyImport_AppendInittab` needs to be called before `Py_Initialize`. I can't finalize and then initialize the engine again. The problem is that now I need to append some modules after `Py_Initialize`. Is there a way to do it?

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem by doing this:

```
if (Py_IsInitialized()) {
    PyImport_AddModule(module_name);
    PyObject* pyModule = moduleInitFunc();
    PyObject* sys_modules = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
    PyDict_SetItemString(sys_modules, module_name, pyModule);
    Py_DECREF(pyModule);
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107783/create-a-python3-module-at-runtime-while-initialize-an-embedded-python).